# My application chain-reboots for no obvious reason, then crashes

Tags: android, android-ndk

My Android application reboots all the time, for no obvious reason. There isn't any crash or stacktrace for me to debug, the application starts, loads a wrapper that calls my native libraries, and a (very brief) moment after that, it restarts.

The application has a new PID (watching this through Android Studio/logcat), and when watching the Android emulator, it seems like the application is frozen, with a white screen and nothing being displayed. After a while (sometimes 3 reboots, sometimes 15), the application crashes with the following "trace":

```
com.stack.overflow.librarytestapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x10 in tid 25652 (librarytestapp)
                  [ 02-26 11:50:07.622  1264: 1264 W/         ]
                  debuggerd: handling request: pid=25652 uid=10087 gid=10087 tid=25652
```

The application depends upon an `.aar` file (Android library), which contains JNI code to C libraries. These libraries are cross-compiled using the Android NDK toolchains, and they use a cross-compiled OpenSSL library.

I know for a fact that the C library works properly. There aren't any warning nor errors during the compilation, and I generate everything for both `x86` and `arm`. When looking at the generated `.apk`, these files are embedded in the `libs` folder, as follow:

```
libs/
  |- x86/
      |- libagent.so   ; C library
      |- libclient.so  ; C library
      |- libcrypto.so  ; OPENSSL
      |- libssl.so     ; OPENSSL
  |- arm/
      |- libagent.so   ; C library
      |- libclient.so  ; C library
      |- libcrypto.so  ; OPENSSL
      |- libssl.so     ; OPENSSL
```

Could anyone help me with this issue? It's driving me crazy. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** After some digging around, it seems like this happens when I call the initialization method from `libclient.so`, which is the one using OpenSSL. `libagent.so`'s initialization doesn't use OpenSSL. Could it be related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is just crashing inside native library.

`fault addr 0x10` most probably means that some data was not initialised (NULL + 0x10).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Since the library works for sure, it most likely comes from my JNI bindings. The lack of stack trace kinda surprised me... I'll do some logging here and there to locate the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the lack of stack trace is expected behaviour in case of crashes in native code